# List All installed chat/messaging APP in Tizen mobile 2.4

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to develop an app which will show list of all messaging / chat apps like **WHATSAPP, TELEGRAM , FACEBOOK MESSANGER** etc installed in mobile phone.

I know by observing certain set of  permission required by apps like **INTERNET, READ CONTACTS, MESSAGING** we can find out such apps but this is not 100% true every time and in each case.

Please help me to solve this problem. Is there any mechanism to find out such apps.

Thanks

Comment: One way is to make a list of package names and then check if those packages are installed or not. Then you can show those in your app's list.
You can find a code snippet for app package info here https://developer.tizen.org/community/code-snippet/embed/11303

Comment: @nafser33 Thanks for your reply, yeah that is one way.. But we can;t list all chat apps (it will be bad coding practice), and in future if any new  app will come in tizen store , we need to modify the code.  Looking for some alternatives,  Heard about [https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Apps ] , Lets see we can make a matrix of such apps.